# Selecting deep columns in pyarrow.dataset parquet

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Let's say I have a deeply nested arrow table like:

```
pyarrow.Table
arr: struct<arr: struct<a: list<item: int64 not null> not null, b: list<item: int64 not null> not null> not null>
  child 0, arr: struct<a: list<item: int64 not null> not null, b: list<item: int64 not null> not null> not null
      child 0, a: list<item: int64 not null> not null
          child 0, item: int64 not null
      child 1, b: list<item: int64 not null> not null
          child 0, item: int64 not null
----
arr: [
  -- is_valid: all not null
  -- child 0 type: struct<a: list<item: int64 not null> not null, b: list<item: int64 not null> not null>
    -- is_valid: all not null
    -- child 0 type: list<item: int64 not null>
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
    -- child 1 type: list<item: int64 not null>
[[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5]]]
```

I can write this to a parquet dataset with `pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset`.

With the now deprecated `pyarrow.parquet` module, I could choose to read a selection of one or more of the leaf nodes like this:

```
pf = pa.ParquetDataset("temp.parq/")
pf.read(columns=["arr.arr.a.list.item"])
```

How do I achieve this with the `pyarrow.dataset` API? As far as I can tell, I can only select top-level fields, in this case ["arr"], which would get me both leaf nodes, not just one.

Whilst `.to_table(columns=)` is promising, it loses the original record structure of the data, so that if I needed to pick more than one leaf out of many, they would all be independent:

cf

```
> ds.to_table().to_pydict()
{'arr': [{'arr': {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 4, 5]}}, ...

> ds.to_table(columns={'leaf': pyarrow.dataset.field('arr', 'arr', 'a')}).to_pydict()
{'leaf': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]}

leaf: list<item: int64 not null> not null
    child 0, item: int64 not null
```

but it should be

```
{'arr': [{'arr': {'a': [1, 2, 3]}}, ..

arr: struct<arr: struct<a: list<item: int64 not null> not null, b: list<item: int64 not null> not null> not null>
  child 0, arr: struct<a: list<item: int64 not null> not null, b: list<item: int64 not null> not null> not null
    child 0, a: list<item: int64 not null> not null
      child 0, item: int64 not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema is the following:

```py
import pyarrow as pa

schema = pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field(
            "arr",
            pa.struct(
                [
                    pa.field(
                        "arr",
                        pa.struct(
                            [
                                pa.field(
                                    "a",
                                    pa.list_(pa.int64())),
                                pa.field(
                                    "b",
                                    pa.list_(pa.int64()))
                            ]
                        ))
                ]
            ))
    ])
```

and you want to remove `b` so the sub schema is this one:

```
sub_schema = pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field(
            "arr",
            pa.struct(
                [
                    pa.field("arr",
                             pa.struct(
                                 [
                                     pa.field("a", pa.list_(pa.int64())),
                                 ]
                             ))
                ]
            ))
    ])
```

I can't think of a way to achieve is with dataset. `to_table` uses [`from_dataset`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.html#pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.from_dataset) which would flatten the extracted field.

Also it doesn't look like changing the schema of the dataset works: `ds.replace_schema(sub_schema)` throws an `ArrowTypeError`

But you can load the dataset in a table and cast that table, which works:

```
table = ds.to_table()
table.cast(sub_schema)
```

Another option is to provide the sub_schema when loading the dataset:

```
pyarrow.dataset.dataset('./my_ds/',  schema=sub_schema).to_table()
```

Comment: Thanks. Also useful, but unfortunately not the equivalent of what deprecated pyarrow.parquet can do (i.e., not load the unnecessary columns at all).

Comment: You could provide the sub_schema when loading (see my edit).

Comment: Great! How do you select the set of leaf columns from the schema to make the subschema - you have done it by hand.

Comment: I think you'd have to write a function that returns a modified version of the original schema, but it's not trivial.

Comment: :( a real shame.

Comment: This answer contains the way forward, so I will accept it. Perhaps we can edit it to be a bit clearer. Also, for my specific use case, awkward-array can easily manipulate schemas and produce the paired arrow schema for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [dataset field expression](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.field.html) supports multiple (or tuple of) names.

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
 
dataset.to_table(columns={'leaf': ds.field('arr', 'a', ...)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question to show why this is not what I am after.